# Looping Nested Loops

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this except with over 40 more

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => name
            [cost] => 20
            [firstname] =>
                (
                    [0] => first 1
                    [1] => first 2
                )
            [lastname] =>
                (
                    [0] => last 1
                    [1] => last 2
                )
            [username] =>
                (
                    [0] => username 1
                    [1] => username 2
                )
        )
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => name
            [cost] => 20
            [firstname] =>
                (
                    [0] => first 1
                    [1] => first 2
                )
            [lastname] =>
                (
                    [0] => last 1
                    [1] => last 2
                )
            [username] =>
                (
                    [0] => username 1
                    [1] => username 2
                )
        )
(
```

I am doing something like this to get the non nested arrays:

```
foreach($data as $row){
    echo $row->id
}
```

but what would I do to get the nested arrays? I wanna be able to display them as:

firstname lastname

username

Comment: Why do You have few objects with arrays of firstnames?

Comment: What I have is a product then the review, the names are all the people who reviewed

Comment: You have 3 arrays in each object. Do every array have the same length?

Comment: No they dont they can have 0 to 5

Comment: Are they the same length in one object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($data as $row){
    echo $row->firstname[0] . ' ' . $row->lastname[0] . '<br/>' . $row->username[0];
}
```

edit:

You should organize your array a bit better, if these are people who did product reviews:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => name
            [cost] => 20
            [reviews] => Array(
                [0]=>
                    (
                        [firstname] => "Bob"
                        [lastname] => "Jacob"
                        [username] => "bobjacob543"
                    )
                [1] = >
                    (...
            )
        )
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
```

Then you can do

```
foreach($data as $row){
    foreach($row->reviews as $review){
        echo $review->firstname . ' ' . $review->lastname . '<br/>' . $review->username;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: That only gives me the first value of firstnames how would I then get the others.

Comment: How would I reorganize my array, its being pulled from a mysql? also it cant have anywhere from 0 to 5